# Do Domain Events in Domain Driven Design hide the intent?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Using Domain Events is widely endorsed practice for DDD applications, but there are scenarios that prove tricky for me.

I was working recently on an application where business logic required that when new user is created, that user is also created in three separate subsystems. So basically if you use transaction script approach it would look something like:

```
public void CreateUser()
{
    CreateUserInSystemA();
    CreateUserInSystemB();
    CreateUserInSystemC();
}
```

The approach I was looking at was using Domain Events, so the entry point looked something like:

```
public void CreateUser()
{
    CreateUserInSystemA();
}
```

Then `CreateUserInSystemA` would raise a domain event when the user was created. Then handler for that event would create user in system B, raise another domain event, and another handler would run that will create user in system C.
All this was set up, during registration of DI container so this was pretty much hardwired.

So the question is:

1) Doesn't this approach effectively hides domain logic? It is not easy by looking at CreateUser method to see what we are really doing.

2) What if (as happened in our case), you will have a new workflow where you just need to create users in systems A and B - thus`CreateUserInSystemC` should not be called? If we used existing `CreateUserInSystemB` implementation, it will raise domain event and hard-wired `CreateUserInSystemC` will run regardless.

What is the best approach to handle this scenario in proper DDD way? Should we use Application Service layer and simply expose two separate methods for both workflows, and do not base flow on Domain Events?

Answer (score 1):

To me, Domain is a sub-system on its own. In your case, you have several systems interconnected. In such a case, your event is an inter-system event, not a domain event.

Thus, fire an event depending on the relations between your sub-systems. From each Domain (sub-system) point of view, other sub-systems are integration layers, probably with their own domain models inside.

So, answers to your questions would be:

1) No, because the approach is completely related to the systems integration.

2) Flow changes require changes in the integration behavior, not to the sub-systems.

One more point: what I mean by sub-system is similar to the services. Each domain has a service that it interacts with. And services are usually connected with interactions (SOA system with multiple services is an implementation example). Plus, each domain can be a service as well, exposed through the service layer probably.